# How do I remove the blank space on the right side of my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble removing the blank space on the right side of my website and I am really not sure where the error is. I can't really pinpoint when this happened exactly, I think it's when I padded the text next to the animation square. Here's an image of [my website with blank space on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcjr2.png)

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "25px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "35px";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Carter One', cursive;
  background-color:#1B1D37;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(43,171,217,1) 0%, rgba(0,130,200,1) 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
.box {
    padding:150px 150px 2500px;
    font-size:30px
}
.card {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 1170px;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 2.6em 3.8em;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 40%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
    0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
    0 16px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
    0 32px 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),
    0 64px 64px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.note::after {
  content: '';
  width: 20%;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  background-color: #AFAFAF;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(43,171,217,1) 0%, rgba(0,130,200,1) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.8em;
  left: 0;
}
.note {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #8A8A8A;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 4em;
}

/* Scroller styling */
.scroller {
  height: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 10em;
}
.scroller > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide 5s infinite;
  font-weight: bold;
  
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }
  25% {
    top: -1.2em;
  }
  50% {
    top: -2.4em;
  }
  75% {
    top: -3.6em;
  }
}
.Colortxt {
    color: white;
}
.hero-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../image/OUTSIDER.png");
  filter: blur(8px);
  webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  height: 70%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top:25%

}


.hero-text {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #151626;
  padding: 90px 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}

#navbar #logo {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#navbar-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  #navbar {
    padding: 20px 10px !important;
  }
  #navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #navbar-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
.txtdescriptor {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>We are artists.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylez.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Carter+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/java1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="navbar">
  <a href="#default" id="logo">Unlikely Duo.</a>
  <div id="navbar-right">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#contact">Our Works</a>
    <a href="#how">Method</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hero-image">
</div>
 <div class="hero-text">
    <h1 style="font-size:50px">We are artists.</h1>
    <h2>Visuals and sound.</h2>
  </div>
<div style="position:relative; right:300px; top:400px;">
   <div class="card">
    <h1>We do    
      <div class="scroller">
        <span>
          Art<br/>
          Music<br/>
          Albums<br/>
          Concepts<br/>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="position:relative; left: 790px; top:300px;"
    <div class="txtdescriptor">
    <h2> We're a duo of arts and sound. <br/>We specialize from anything to concept art to making songs for your <br/>project.</h2>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider not using relative positioning? Use another tool, like flexbox or grid?

Comment: I put it in a jsbin and got this: https://jsbin.com/qaracugeho/edit?output (also, given your script name, please note that the language is called JavaScript and very different from Java, a completely separate language)

Comment: You can set width of you text description like `width:fit-content`. Also, you didn't close correctly the div close to txtdescriptor.